# PHP Cannot display items with " ' " in them

Tags: javascript, php, web, dynamic-loading

I have a list of food items that can be selected to be ordered. Names without " ' " work fine, however, names such as Pasqua Nero D'Avola Sicilia do not work. I tried replacing ' with \' but still the same problem. The code is as follows (x is item):

```
            var newRow = "<tr><td>"+x+"</td><td>€"+y.toFixed(2)+"</td><td><input type=\"button\" onclick=\"subtract("+y+")\" value = \"X\"></td></tr>"
```

Comment: Have you tried `addslashes()`?

Comment: No, none of them seem to work.

Comment: Could you try that? Another solution would replace the `'` with a underscore or another character and then replace it again on the server-side.

Comment: What exactly means "don't work"? What happens instead? And in general, try using `htmlentities(x)` instead of just `x`.

Comment: the function is not called, however, if i replace " ' " with " ` " it works

Answer (score 0):

Use $item['name'] inside *htmlspecialchars()* function

`htmlspecialchars($item['name'])`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the characters as the ' conflicts within attributes.

Here is a function you can use to escape food names safely:

```
function jsattrencode($x){
    $x=htmlentities(htmlspecialchars($x,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8',false),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF8');     
    return $x;   
}
```

usage for your needs:

```
$('#item').append("<tr style='font-size: 16px;'><td><a href='#' onclick=\'addItem(\"<?php echo jsattrencode($item['name']);?>\",<?php echo jsattrencode($item['price']);?>)\'><?php echo $item['name'];?></td><td>&euro;<?php echo $item['price'];?></a></td></tr>");
```

Note: ensure both your php and html charsets are set to utf-8